# pygame with FULLSCREEN flag renders content scaled

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I'm using pygame on a raspberry pi.
This same code used to cover the full screen at 800x600, now, at 1280x720 it doesn't, and it's not over/underscan:

Pygame example output:
[image: pygame example]

Video playback via omxplayer:
[image: video playback via omxplayer]

All the code in the pygame example image is just a demo for the problem:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720)) #, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
time.sleep(45)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list_modes` function which returns a list of available full screen resolutions:

```
modes = pygame.display.list_modes()
if modes: # check if the list is not empty
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(modes[0], pygame.FULLSCREEN) # use the first one
else:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600)) # use a default resolution
```

**Note:** if you have problems with high DPI scaling on Windows (e. g. a part of your display is not visible), you can use this code to fix them:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
```